# Is it appropriate to have a web service have more than one responsibility?

Tags: web-services

I was having a discussion with a colleague about Web Services.  Now we both agree that a Web Method should only have one responsibility, as per single responsibility principle, but what about the entire service?  I always considered the Web Service as a gateway, his argument was that if the web service has methods that have a different area functionally or from a domain perspective then those methods should be housed in a completely separate web service.  I'm looking to see what the community has to say on the matter.

Should a web service with functionally different methods be housed in different services and URLs?

OR

Should a web service that's considered an internal gateway house methods that are functionally different but related by the gateway concept?

Comment: This should be migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you give me a bit more info on the use of it as an internal gateway..some context? @Erik - agreed

Comment: @RalphWillgoss by internal gateway, I mean a web service that is non-public facing and would be called from publicly accessible sites or services to alter the database, etc.

Comment: @ErikPhilips is there a way I can do that or do I have to wait for a moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will be a matter of opinion, but we chose to structure our web services using the same guidelines as used for class libraries in C# (Since we're a .NET shop).  Similar funcitonality goes into similar web services, named to clearly define what to expect in each web service.

- RetailLocationServices
- EmployeeInformationServices
- FinancialServices
- etc

Answer (score 0):

How about a model that consits of one url and then functional areas:

```
http://api.<yourdomain>/1.0/Finance/
http://api.<yourdomain>/1.0/Users/
http://api.<yourdomain>/1.0/<FunctionalArea>/
```

You could omit the version directory if needed.
In my experience with working API's at some point you'll want/need to roll out another version. Some people do this with query string params, I prefer it in the url for visibility to the caller.

You could then vertically slice the development of your services, therefore upgrades to one won't affect the others. Some auto-build-magic could then help you deploy them too.